# как в xamarin.Forms отобразить Listview снизу вверх

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Я написала небольшую программу в целях обучения, где вывожу список на экран, ListView выводит элементы сверху, я бы хотела сделать, что бы он начинался снизу подскажите, как это можно сделать или может какие-статьи. Буду очень благодарна. Вот пример моего ListView и пример фото.

```
<ListView
            ItemTapped="MyListView_ItemTapped"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" 
            RefreshCommand="{Binding UpdateList}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource chatDataTemplateSelector}"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList}"
            Background="#1D2733" 
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
            RefreshControlColor="Cyan"  
            Margin="0,0,0,0" 
            SeparatorColor="Transparent"  
            x:Name="MyListView" 
            HasUnevenRows="true" 
            >
        </ListView>
```

На фото попыталась показать где должен начинаться список

[image: Пример]

Comment: @Anatol, мне кажется это сайт не для политики

Comment: `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"`. Если нужно еще инвертировать элементы, то это уже процесс добавления, где надо добавлять в начало списка, а не в его конец. Тем самым будет у вас снизу вверх идти все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо =)